# iOS: developing audio (music) streaming from server

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I'm researching to start developing an audio streaming apps. First thing I'd like to ask is the framework to use for it. I've tested `DOUAudioStreamer` , `tumtumtum/StreamingKit` , `RadioKit` and etc.

The framework needs to be able to seek a song from certain seconds with low latency. Spotify has that amazing seek feature i.e. find a song you've never listened before and play it, then slide the time slider to the middle, the song continues to play with low latency as if it has downloaded the whole song before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do some predictive analysis as to what songs the user will listen to next, i.e. start caching songs before they actually start to play. That will at least improve the experience somewhat.